# css margin-bottom is not working

Tags: html, css

I want a little margin space between product `div` but bottom margin is not working. I've used `position: absolute` too but nothing changes. Kindly help me because I'm doing my project.

[Output of current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Y5Q.png)

```css
#mai-contant {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 840px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: right;
}

.product {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 271px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mai-contant">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="product"> 
        <img src="../images/004.jpg"> 
      </div>              
      <div class="product"> 
        <img src="../images/004.jpg"> 
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        <img src="../images/004.jpg"> 
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="product"> 
        <img src="../images/004.jpg">  
      </div>
      <div class="product"> 
        <img src="../images/004.jpg">   
      </div>
      <div class="product"> 
        <img src="../images/004.jpg">
      </div>
    </li>       
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: It is perfectly working. Check it https://codepen.io/sirajalam049/pen/BmpzxB and try changing `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Same here. What seems to be the problem? "not working" is not a good enough problem description, not even if you repeat it 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

The bullet points are breaking the flow. Remove the list styling:

```
#mai-contant > ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css line of code:

```
#mai-contant ul li:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```